# How to add to excludes alerts on smartmontool

Tags: linux, debian, syslog, smart, nvme

I faced with problem and hope for your help.
Started getting notifications from smart on Debian 10 server:

```bash
Device: /dev/nvme1, Critical Warning (0x04): Reliability
```

Found that this alert causing because next attribute:

```bash
Percentage Used:  107%
```

I also found information that it is not critical if the other indicators are normal and in my case they are normal:

```bash
Available Spare: 100%
Available Spare Threshold: 10%
```

So there is no reasons to change the nvme drives, considering that the messages are coming from both drives. I found it difficult to add these messages to ignore using `/etc/smartd.conf`

NVME model `SAMSUNG MZVLB512HBJQ-00000`, I've found that `Percentage Used` attribute ID is 5.
Tried to add this attribute ID to excludes in `/etc/smartd.conf` like this:

```bash
DEVICESCAN  -d nvme -I 5
```

But get alerts again when testing it:

```bash
~ smartd -c  /etc/smartd.conf -q onecheck
...
Device: /dev/nvme0, opened
Device: /dev/nvme0, SAMSUNG MZVLB512HBJQ-00000,
Device: /dev/nvme1, opened
Device: /dev/nvme1, SAMSUNG MZVLB512HBJQ-00000,
Device: /dev/nvme0, opened NVMe device
Device: /dev/nvme0, Critical Warning (0x04): Reliability
Device: /dev/nvme1, opened NVMe device
Device: /dev/nvme1, Critical Warning (0x04): Reliability
Started with '-q onecheck' option. All devices sucessfully checked once.
smartd is exiting (exit status 0)
```

Maybe someone has encountered how exactly you can add to the ignore this type of alerts for nvme drive? Thank you in advance.